# Poor CMRR in differential attenuator

Tags: differential, attenuator

I need to design a differential attenuator. The core design is a series of resistors with capacitors in parallel. POT in the middle represented as “U1” is used to balance both input branches to have the same DC gain. Trimmer caps are used to match the time constant. My initial approach was to match the time constant of each RC loop: T1=T3 and T2=T4. When a single side of the attenuator is tested with a square wave in the following way: ground of signal generator is connected to one side of the attenuator and output of the signal generator to the other input of the attenuator. The results are acceptable. However, this approach has the following flaw T1≠T2. This degrades the CMRR performance if the signal is connected to both inputs to the attenuator in respect to the ground. Is there any way of reducing this CMRR performance degradation without adding additional trimmers or pots? Currently, I use the lowest tolerance components possible for that application.[image]

Comment: You haven't drawn a differential attenuator. You've drawn two single-ended attenuators with provision to tweak their gains. To get a true differential attenuator you lose the ground connection. Then you are relying on the CMRR of whatever is connected to the OUT terminals. Driving the IN terminals in a balanced way will help.

Comment: How can T1 (a resistor) = T3 (a variable capacitor)?

Comment: I'm quite sure T1 means R1C1 and T3 means R3(C3+Cvar)

Comment: @Andyaka T1=R1C1.

Comment: @Neil_UK GND in the schematic relates only to the common-mode signal that I injected into both inputs while grounding the signal generator at that point. In normal operation it should not be accessible it is a reference point for instrumentation amplifier connected to both +Out and - Out.